# Javascript works different on host server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, calculation

My MVC Core project works on my localhost fine, but when I upload it to my AWS EC2 server it gives me different result. I insert values to MSSQL server on internet but I don't think it is because of SQL side.

```
function adetOlcuKontrolEt()
    {
        metretulHesapla();
        var yuzdefark = document.getElementById("yuzde_fark").value;
        var oran = 0;
        var iskonto = document.getElementById("iskonto").value;

        var birim = document.getElementById("BirimM2").value;
        var adet = document.getElementById("Adet").value; // adet burası
        var sonuc = eval(birim) * eval(adet);

        document.getElementById("ToplamM2").value = sonuc.toFixed(3);


        var birim = document.getElementById("BirimM2").value;
        if (birim <= 0.20) {
            document.getElementById("yuzde_fark").value = "20";
        }

        var birimM2 = document.getElementById("BirimM2").value;
        var orann = "20";

        if (birimM2 <= 0.200) {
            sonucc = (birimM2 + ((birimM2 / 100) * orann));
        }

        var x = document.getElementById("Genislik").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("Yukseklik").value;
        var sonuc22 = eval(x / 1000) * eval(y / 1000);

        document.getElementById("BirimM2").value = sonuc22.toFixed(3);

        var fiyatt = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.SATISFIYAT1));
        var iskontoo = iskonto;
        var farkk = yuzdefark;
        var sonuc = ((fiyatt * (1 - (iskontoo / 100))) * (1 + (farkk / 100)));
        document.getElementById("Tutar1M2").value = sonuc.toFixed(2);

        var toplammetrekare = document.getElementById("ToplamM2").value;
        var toplamfiyat = document.getElementById("Tutar1M2").value;
        var sonuc = ((toplammetrekare * toplamfiyat));
        document.getElementById("ToplamTutar").value = sonuc.toFixed(2);

        //document.getElementById("ekle").focus();
                if (document.getElementById("Adet").value == "0" || document.getElementById("Adet").value == "") {
                alert('Adet girmediniz.');
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById('ekle').click();



    }
```

These are my same results of localhost and AWS host:

[localhost result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMDPB.png)

[awshost result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNQtF.png)

Comment: add the html, and add the server configurations, for the table, ie the field types.

Comment: `var birim = document.getElementById("BirimM2").value;` and  `var birim = document.getElementById("BirimM2").value;` are the same value..... FYI

Comment: yes, but that's not the reason of problem.